# Python got Stucked and not able to auto post via telegram bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am not able to post via telegram bot into my channel, I created it and added as a admin and in the below code I tried to fetch products from amazon and auto posting in telegram group but I am not able to do that.

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

# Initialize your Telegram bot
bot_token = 'TOKEN_ID'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)

# Set up your Amazon PA-API credentials
amazon_access_key = 'ACCESS_KEY'
amazon_secret_key = 'SECRET_KEY'
amazon_associate_tag = 'ASSOCIATE_TAG'

amazon = AmazonAPI(amazon_access_key, amazon_secret_key, amazon_associate_tag)

# Implement a command handler to fetch and post product information
def fetch_deals(update, context):
    chat_id = 'CHANNEL_CHAT_ID'  # Replace with the chat ID of your group
    products = amazon.search(Keywords='todays deals best offer', SearchIndex='All')

    num_products_to_fetch = 10  # Set the desired number of products to fetch
    count = 0  # Counter variable to keep track of the fetched products

    for product in products:
        message = f"Today's Deal Alert!\n\nTitle: {product.title}\nPrice: {product.price_and_currency[0]} {product.price_and_currency[1]}\nURL: {product.offer_url}\nImage: {product.large_image_url}"
        context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, photo=product.large_image_url, caption=message)

        count += 1  # Increment the counter

        if count >= num_products_to_fetch:
            break  # Exit the loop after fetching the desired number of products

    print("Product Information Fetched")
    updater.stop()
    updater.is_idle = False

updater = Updater(token=bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

deal_handler = CommandHandler('fetchdeals', fetch_deals)
dispatcher.add_handler(deal_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: I got this error when I run this code:    telegram.error.Conflict: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
Error while getting Updates: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.